# Crash on Firefox, slow on Internet Explorer and devices (demo provided)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, three.js, device

I researched a lot about this problem and I'm going crazy trying to understand why my example is causing a crash on Firefox, and runs VERY SLOWLY con Internet Explorer and mobile devices.

I'm rendering a big (4K) image on a sphere geometry, trying to create a kind of a pano viewer. In the real application, we can go from one place to the next one, clicking on the invisible shapes that are created inside the sphere.

In the real app, we have a big (4K) video rendering so we have some stuff in a certain area that moves in a loop. However, for this demo I commented those lines (addVideoTexture and renderVideo), so I understand this is not the issue here.

Pay attention to our raycaster, I suspect it is causing big performance problems, but I don't know any other way of detecting when our mouse is going over an "action hotspot" (look above) or a "indicator hotspot" (invisible areas that would allow to go to other places when clicking).

```
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
hits = raycaster.intersectObjects(indicatorHotspotPlane, false);
```

The problem is that this demo is causing a crash on Firefox, and going very very slow on plenty of devices and Internet Explorer.

Thanks a lot...

Ricardo

Here is an example where you can test it:

https://jsfiddle.net/ggL3uemh/13/

The ThreeJS version is **r89**

The browsers where it causes problems are **Firefox and Internet Explorer**, and I see **some iOS devices** going slow too.

Comment: It's not crashing on firefox for me in your fiddle

Comment: True, I just found out that it is a problem with my computer or graphics card. I even get a blue screen sometimes, and every time WebGL is crashing.

Comment: What about IE?? did you try? do you think that the performance is so poor because of such big textures?

Comment: It's not loading in IE 11 or < IE 11. Working very well on edge

Comment: any idea why?  Thanks

Comment: Maybe somebody know about octrees? do you think we can add it to our project so maybe we will improve a lot the search of intersections? https://codepen.io/Ryan-James/pen/mJMBwP?editors=1000